# Gradle project refresh failed .Error:Could not get resource

Tags: android-studio, gradle, junit

I am new to android development. Just download and install the android studio and sdk manager files .After creating a new project , android studio is getting an error :

Gradle 'First' project refresh failed
Error:Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.

I have searched a lot but haven't got any answer .Please help to solve this annoying problem .Thanks to advance .

Comment: Run the gradle script with `--stacktrace` and add the script and the error to the question. You can do that from command line.

Comment: Problem is solved !!

Answer (score 0):

However,I have found a solution for my problem."junit-4.12.jar" was not in that url .So, I have changed in build.gradle .

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}
this block to

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }

}
```

}

And it solved my problem .

Comment: This is very unlikely. jcenter certainly contains JUnit 4.12: http://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/ Also you can simply use mavenCentral() and not specify it using the URL.